How to combine two texture in geometry nodes after a Distribute point on faces node
My first objective is to have a point cloud from a 3D scan with some points glowing.
Everything is working; the color of the points comes from my texture. However, when I want to add a second material and join it to my nodes, it's not working. The 'Join Geometry' node only keeps the material I put on the top and erases the other one. I want to have both textures at the same time.
If anyone has a solution, I can't get over it.


Could it be that a point cloud is supporting only one material ? Not like a mesh where materials are attached to faces, so more than one is supported. In this case, you could try to attach a named attribute to the points, then to choose the color/material in the shader based on this attribute.

@StefLAncien I think you are correct : I'm unable to have 2 materials with points but with Instances on Points no problem.

When connecting the Selection socket of a Set Material node attached to a Point Cloud, a warning is displayed : "Point clouds only support a single material; selection input can not be a field".

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Following is a proposal with a single material but storing directly a color as named attribute, used afterward in the Shader Editor.

Resources: 

Oh yes it's working thanks!
(I just had to create another named attribute connected to emission in shader editor to make it glow)
